# Where is the subject?

Tags: subject

A SlowGerman.com episode contains the following:

> Und die berühmte Toblerone-Schokolade wird nur in Bern hergestellt und von dort aus in 120 Länder verkauft. Denk daran, wenn Du sie das nächste Mal am Flughafen siehst. Bezahlt wird übrigens mit Schweizer Franken.

In the last sentence where is the subject? Is this correct German with no subject?

> Bezahlt wird übrigens mit Schweizer Franken.

I realize that German permits the subject to be implied, so that it might be taken to be **es** or **man** in this case, but it still should point clearly to an actor, shouldn't it? The passage says that the chocolate is sold in 120 countries and paid for in Swiss Francs. But I know I do not pay for it in Swiss Francs when I buy it in my country. So who are we talking about here? Although the grammar may permit the particular construction it seems like the language should expect clarity anyway.

The sentence is talking about payment but leaves the subject indefinite. Does this mean that all payments are in Swiss Francs? Is it saying that whenever you buy it at the airport it must be paid for in Swiss Francs? Are all countries paying for it in Swiss Francs? The German language ability to leave out the subject appears to have enticed the author, in this case, to be lazy and the result is confusing.

Comment: Same topic: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/what-is-the-subject-in-da%c3%9f-meinem-gesuch-stattgegeben-werde/34307#34307

Comment: The "missing" subject is unrelated to the problem of who is paying in Swiss francs, as the subject would say *what* is being paid for and not who is doing the paying.

Comment: Somebody has to be doing the paying, however they pay and whatever way they are paying. It seems to me that had an explicit, definite subject been present in this sentence it would have had to at least imply who was doing the paying in some sense, otherwise I do not know what this passage is actually telling me.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was to an interesting discussion of the grammar. But in this case the grammar is less an issue than the meaning.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning in the given context either. My understanding would be that this sentence has nothing to do with Toblerone any more, but is the continuation of a more general text about Switzerland.

Comment: Well, maybe I am misunderstanding what the author is trying to say. Here is the complete text: [SlowGerman.com](https://slowgerman.com/2020/08/11/die-schweiz-sg-212/). The passage is at the end of the 4th paragraph from the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Martin Durrell explains the subjectless werden-passive in "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage".

> The *werden*-passive can be used without a subject to denote an
> activity in general. The construction  is widely used in spoken and
> written German. The agent is unspecified, so that there is no
> indication of who is performing the action. The verb has 3rd-person
> singular endings. No comparable construction exists in English.
> Examples:
>
> *Sie hörten, wie im Nebenzimmer **geredet wurde***. / They heard someone
> talking in the next room
>
> *Hier darf nicht **geraucht werden***. / Smoking is not allowed here.
>
> *Vor Hunden **wird gewarnt***. / Beware of dogs.
>
> *Heute ist mit den Bauarbeiten **begonnen worden***. / They started building
> today.

In "German in Review: Lehrbuch der deutschen Grammatik", Sparks and Van Horn Vail add an additional useful piece of information about the subjectless *werden*-passive as follows.

> When no agent is expressed in a passive sentence, its active
> counterpart is often formed by using ... **man** as its subject:
>
> Passive: *Auf internationalen Flügen **wird** nicht mehr **geraucht**.*
>
> Active: *Auf internationalen Flügen **raucht man** nicht mehr.*

Comment: The Vorfeld slot can also be occupied by _es_: _Es wird vor Hunden gewarnt_, _es darf hier nicht geraucht werden_. Then you have a "pseudo-subject".

Comment: @phipsgabler Objection. The *es* is not a pseudo-subject, it is a syntactic expletive which is only there to fill a void in the sentence. That’s why it can disappear upon reordering.

Comment: That's why I called it pseudo. It may seem to behave like a proper subject on first sight, but fails to do so after some more thinking.